# is it possible to search a value in multiple columns using in clause in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, in-clause

I wonder if it is possible to search a value in columns using in clause having column names as in elements.
for instance :

```
$username_or_mail = 'value';
select * from users where $username_or_mail in(username,email);
```

where username and email are column names in table users.
I tried this and seems that it is working but i want to be sure if i'm right.

Comment: The SQL seems correct but i'm not sure of this aproach is valid. This would means multiple columns would share the same value which would be a design flaw

Comment: @DarkBee I think the OP is using this as a more expressive shorthand for multiple `OR` predicates sharing the same operands. This would be used for a "Enter your username or email address"-type login form that accepts either.

Comment: @ [DarkBee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee) actually i have a login form where users enter their username or email to login, then i search that value in columns username and email to check if user is attempting to login using his/her email or username.

Comment: @DarkBee It is uncommon but it is not necessarily a design flaw

Comment: I see. It translates in an `OR` rather than an `AND` which I assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would I be right in assuming you're using this for a "Enter your username or e-mail address and password to login" login form?

If so, then your SQL code is correct, but hints at a possible design flaw: what happens if someone has a username that is also the email address of another user? This could be used as a malicious attack (i.e. hijack another user's account by making your username equal to the victim's email address).

There is a solution/workaround: simply check for the `'@'` character and ensure that email addresses contain `@` and similarly ensure that no username contains `@` either.

...and if you're going to do that logic, then you might as well optimize the SQL and skip having to check multiple columns (psuedocode):

```
if( $usernameOrEmail contains '@' ) {
    registerParameter("@email", $usernameOrEmail);
    $sql = "SELECT ... WHERE EmailAddress = @email"; // note that "@email" is the syntax for query parameters in MySQL.
} else {
    registerParameter("@userName", $usernameOrEmail);
    $sql = "SELECT ... WHERE UserName = @userName";

}
```

Comment: @ [DAi] (http://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) Thanks for the quick answer and yes, you are right,
I want that functionality, regarding malicious attack: i also check users password beside username_or_mail. so i think there is no need of checking if it is username or email, again i prefer your logic since it optimizes sql query.

Comment: @hussainfrotan sounds good - I trust you've cryptographically hashed and salted those passwords first?

Comment: @ [Dai] (http://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) i just md5 the password and then store it in database is that fine?

Comment: @hussainfrotan MD5 is insecure, use SHA-2 instead.